# JavaFX: stage's minHeight considering titlebar's height

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

I'm currently building a small UI application for personal purpose and I ran into a problem. Here is some code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ui.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("My app");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMinHeight(608.0);
    stage.setMinWidth(1080.0);

    stage.show();
}
```

And here's the FXML code assiociated with:

```
<GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" minHeight="608.0" minWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="my.package.MyClass">
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="500.0" prefHeight="500.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="108.0" minHeight="108.0" prefHeight="108.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
    </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

So, my problem is that, at launch, the GridPane will effectively have a height of `608px` but is still resizable to a smaller height. Indeed, it will be resizable until the **stage** will be `608px`, including the title bar's height...

The behaviour I would like to have is that my GridPane can't have a smaller height than `608.0`.

Do you know any ways to do that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you can do `stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());` (and similarly for the width) *after* you call `stage.show()`.

Comment: Wonderful, it works! Many thanks dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @James_D pointed out in a comment, I simply had to modify my code as follow:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ui.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("My app");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();

    stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
    stage.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());
}
```