# JavaFX setOnShown fires before window is visible

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to set the minimum height of a window to the height of the scene it contains + the title bar height (so after showing the window, there's no possibility to shrink it more). Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346746/5459240) answer I wrote:

```
stage.setOnShown(event -> {
     stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
 });
```

It doesn't seem to work though because when the event is fired the window is not even shown on screen and its height is still equal to the height of the scene (title bar is not taken into consideration). My question is then - how to run the code when window is actually visible on the screen?

Comment: Are you looking for `sage.sizeToScene();` method? which sets the width and height of this Window to match the size of the content of this Window's Scene.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this method. But the problem is not with sizing the window but with putting constrains on its minimal size.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the root of the scene to be laid out, and then size the stage to the scene's size:

```
stage.setOnShown(e -> {
    stage.getScene().getRoot().layout();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
});
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageSizeTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
            primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().layout();
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            System.out.printf("[%.1f, %.1f]%n", primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight());
            primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
            primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, 
                new Label("Test one"),
                new Label("Another test"),
                new Label("Another really long label to give the scene some width"),
                new Label("Bottom label"));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @asdfzcx Strange; it works fine for me; you cannot reduce the size of the window below the original size. What platform (OS and JDK version) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux (distro - Solus) and OpenJDK 1.8.0_121.

Comment: @as Yeah... hmm. I wrote and tested it on my Mac and it worked fine. I just tried it on my Ubuntu box and it did the same as you showed. It looks like the height of the window changes at some point after it's displayed; as though the height is set to the height of the scene, then later adjusted to include the height of the title bar. Not sure what kind of workaround would be ok here: I can only come up with hacks (such as waiting a short time and setting the minimum height after the delay, or similar).